# PDO binding variable multiple times in multiple queries

Tags: php, variables, pdo, bind

I was wondering whether there are limitations as per using one PHP variable multiple times for binding values in different sql statements. My code below gives me an error in the ELSE. The IF works fine:

```
$numPresup = $_POST['numPresupuesto'];
$numHist = $_POST['numHistorial'];
$query2 = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_claves WHERE NumPresup = :numPresup AND Historia = :numHist");
$query2-> execute(array(':numHist'=> $numHist,':numPresup' => $numPresup));
$row2=$query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($row2==0) {
$_SESSION['error1']= "Datos no encontrados, por favor introduzca de nuevo sus detalles";
header( 'Location: http://www.abcde.php');
}
else 
{
$query = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_descuentos WHERE NumPresup = :numPresupuesto");
$query-> bindValue(':numPresupuesto',$numPresup);
$query-> execute();
$row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

The error message i get is: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object`

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the return value from that second `prepare` call? I suspect that the query is failing.

Comment: Yes, it works totally fine on its own. It is only within this example where it does not work.

Comment: After the `prepare` line, add in `var_dump($con->ErrorInfo());` and `var_dump($query->ErrorInfo());` - that will show you what the last error message from the database was.

Comment: Done "Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute."

Comment: Then you'll need to close the earlier query - `unset ($query2);` should do the trick, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found:

```
else 
{
$query2->closeCursor();
...
```

I needed to free up my connection.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php